# Merge Javascript arrays within a recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, recursion

I'm running into trouble concatenating "two" arrays during recursion. I start with an empty array and during the function I concatenate it with the new array. The concatenated version becomes the array which is again concatenated with another array within the same function. Following is what I want:

```
var oldArray = [];
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var newArray = [i];
    oldArray = oldArray.concat([newArray]);
}
document.write(oldArray);

produces: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But if I use my actual production code I get a two steps forward, one step back sort of effect.

*written in angular. go() is the wrapping function*

```
var accounts = [];

$http.get('/api/account/', {params:{page:page}}).then(function (result) {
    var count = result.data.count,
        totalPages = Math.ceil(count/10),
        results = result.data.results;

    accounts = accounts.concat(results);

    if (page < totalPages) {
        page++;
        go(page);
    }

    return accounts;
});

produces: [0,1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,7,6,8,7,9]
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with trying to make big code to work at first run, but it is much easier to first write it in the safest way possible even if the structure looks ugly with many functions, etc. Then start reducing and simplifying the code from there (it is millions of times easier to understand what is being done).

Comment: `$http.get` is async, so you can't guarantee the first call will finish before the second call is done. Your `accounts` will be concat with values in non-sequential order.

Comment: console.log(result) for the win and put a breakpoint on accounts=accounts.concat to see what is actually being concatenated.

Comment: @FooL, $http.get is using a promise so it doesn't call itself again until it gets a response from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the assist everyone. Turns out I was calling the function twice in my routing config. Doh! Couple hours waisted there.